# DSP Filter Issues

Tags: c++, filter, signal-processing

I'm fairly new to DSP & still learning. I'm trying to build a multi-slope & multi-mode filter but I am having some issues. Here is my code for the current filter.

```
double Filter::process(double inputValue) {
    if (inputValue == 0.0) return inputValue;
    buf0 += cutoff * (inputValue - buf0 + feedbackAmount * (buf0 - buf1));
    buf1 += cutoff * (buf0 - buf1);
    buf2 += cutoff * (buf1 - buf2);
    buf3 += cutoff * (buf2 - buf3);
    switch (mode) {
    case FILTER_MODE_LOWPASS:
        if (slope) { return buf3; }
        return buf1;
    case FILTER_MODE_HIGHPASS:
        if (slope) { return inputValue - buf3; }
        return inputValue - buf1;
    case FILTER_MODE_BANDPASS:
        if (slope) { return buf0 - buf3; }
        return buf0 - buf1;
    default:
        return 0.0;
    }
}
```

As you can see, it four first-order low pass filters. The "slope" feature is a value of either 0 or 1 based on the parameter you select (which works, I've debugged it and made sure there's no errors). The issue comes with the high-pass and bandpass filters. The low pass works fine and returns the correct value (buf3) which results in a -24dB filter.

The other two, however, seem to be backwards. When slope is set to 24db (slope == 1) for highpass & bandpass, even though its returning the appropriate value (inputvalue - buf3, for example) i am still getting what seems to be a 12dB slope (determined by checking frequency via analyzer & you can tell by the sound produced). I can't seem to figure out where the error is.

Another issue I am having is really annoying aliasing, ie, when i set the lowpass filter to a low cutoff, there are still some high frequencies passing through & you can hear the sound oscillating or something. Feedback is zero and a clean saw is being passed through another plugin. This is only a simple filter plugin that goes through a clip distortion. The rest of the code-

```
//for loop
    *input = mFilter.process(*input);
    if(*input >= 0) {
        *output = std::min(*input, mThreshold);
    } else {
        *output = std::max(*input, -mThreshold);
    }
    *output *= mOutputLevel / mThreshold;
//end loop
```

If any more info is needed, please let me know.

Comment: What types are buf0, buf1, buf2 and buf3?

Comment: At the beginning of the routine you exclude zeros from entering the filter - is there a reason for that?  Did you mean to exclude all zero-valued samples?

Comment: What are the values of the control parameters `cutoff` and `feedbackAmount`?

Comment: cutoff ranges from 0.0 to 0.99.    Feedback follows a calculate feedback method which is: feedbackAmount = resonance + resonance/(1.0 - cutoff);  resonance is another knob, ranges from 0.0 to 1.0

everything that holds a number is of type double, except slope which is an int. The first line (inputValue == 0.0) is to ensure there's no additional processing if there is no audio coming through the filter or if the audio is silent.